# In Python, how do I get this variable assignment to work?

Tags: python

```
# This works until line 7
sex = input("Are you male(m) or female(f)? ")
me = 75 * 52
fe = 80 * 52
ca = input("What is your current age in years? ") * 52
print(sex)  # This is returning the input from the first line.
if sex == m:
    print(f"You have approximately {me - ca} weeks to live. ")
else:
    print(f"You have approximately {fe - ca} weeks to live. ")
```

The variable is assigned a string, but it's not working as a Boolean in the *if* statement.

Comment: The problem is `ca = input("What is your current age in years? ") * 52`. `input()` returns str. Print `ca` to see what you work with

Comment: I think you want `sex == 'm'`.

Comment: `if sex == m` compares `sex` to a **variable** named `m`. If you want to compare to a literal string it's `if sex == 'm'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: @buran That's another problem for sure, but OP first has to get past the hurdle of *"it's not working as a boolean in the if statement"*

Comment: @slothrop, indeed. But that was first error that I saw :-)

Comment: Your assignment to `ca` isn't going to do what you think, either. Since `input` returns a string, `ca` is the result of multiple string concatenations. For example, `'5'* 52` is not `260`, but `'5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555`. (That is, the string `'5'` repeated 52 times.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with this code.

1. `sex == m` is comparing `sex`, a variable to `m`, another variable that was not defined. you need to compare `sex` to `'m'`, a string.
2. `input()` returns a string. you need to convert that string into an integer before multiplying by 52

Here is a correct version for OP's code:

```
sex = input("Are you male(m) or female(f)? ")
me = 75 * 52
fe = 80 * 52
ca = int(input("What is your current age in years? ")) * 52
print(sex)  #  this is returning the input from the first line.
if sex == 'm':
    print(f"You have approximately {me - ca} weeks to live. ")
else:
    print(f"You have approximately {fe - ca} weeks to live. ")
```